# Getting the state of a JCheckBox to a different class in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

The idea is to have two totally different scenarios for my class to do depending on the value of the boolean `isGroupLogsChecked` it receives at the beginning in its constructor:

```
private boolean     isGroupLogsChecked      = false;

public EditorPaneJobLog()
{
    if (isGroupLogsChecked){
        createLayoutForGroupedLogs();
    }
    else {
        createLayout();
    }
        initDefault();
        initListener();
}
```

In order for this to work, the value `isGroupLogsChecked` must be equal to the state of the checkbox `groupLogs` which is calculated in a different class.

```
private JCheckBox    groupLogs      = new JCheckBox(Res.getIntl(Constants.RES+"$GroupLogs"));
```

When the checkbox is checked, `groupLogs.isSelected()` should return (true), which is exactly the value it has in its class.

What I'm trying to do right now is, depending on the value of the checkbox `groupLogs`, I want to retrieve that value in the constructor above. Problem is, I have failed so far to do that because the value is always false, even when it's true, which means the `EditorPaneJobLog` class is not getting the value.

What I have tried so far:

1. Create a getter in the `EditorJob` class (where the value of JCheckBox is calculated) and use the getter in the other class to retrieve the value. However, I always get false which is normal because what I did is the following:

`EditorJob editorJob = new EditorJob();
editorJob.getGroupLogs ----> always false`

What I'm doing here is not getting the value of the checkbox in the other class that has been calculated, I'm getting the value of another instance of the class EditorJob, that's why I keep getting false.

2. Make the checkbox a static field and try to access it directly in the other class by doing `EditorJob.groupLogs` --- Didn't work either, and according to what I saw on SO, it should be avoided at all costs.
3. Storing the value of the checkbox in my database and then retrieve it from there in the other class? Still haven't done this and I was wondering if it's a good idea or not?

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have highlighted the problem:

> `EditorJob editorJob = new EditorJob();` editorJob.getGroupLogs ---->
>   always false
>
> What I'm doing here is not getting the value of the checkbox in the
>   other class that has been calculated, I'm getting the value of another
>   instance of the class EditorJob, that's why I keep getting false.

You need to make sure that `editorJob` is the only instance (or if you plan on having multiple, at least the same instance of EditorJob) that you are concerned with.

One "hack" you can use is having a global interface. **The following is what you want - but it will not compile. We try to access some method of class B from class A.**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A classA = new A();
        B classB = new B();
        classA.getStuffFromB();
    }
}

class A {
    public A() { }

    public void getStuffFromB() {
        // Error because classB will not be able to resolved
        System.out.println(classB.getSomething());
    }
}

class B {
    public B() { }

    public int getSomething() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

**Instead, we can create a new interface, `Globals`, to house instances of our classes. Each class that we want to call another class from must implement our new interface.**

```
public interface Globals {
    A classA = new A();
    B classB = new B();
}
```

Now, we can call getStuffFromB() without error.

```
public class Test implements Globals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        classA.getStuffFromB();
    }
}

class A implements Globals {
    public A() { }

    public void getStuffFromB() {
        System.out.println(classB.getCheckBool());
    }
}

class B {
    private JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox();

    public B() {
        check.setSelected(true);
    }

    public int getSomething() {
        return check.isSelected();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your method, but I'm still getting false for the value of the checkbox even though in its original class the value is true.

Comment: If you can post a [reprex] in your original question, something I can copy/paste and run, it'll be easier to help.

Comment: @JesseJames I've also edited my answer to include a JCheckBox. I set it true in the constructor for class B, and get the value from class A. It returns true - so there might be some other issue for your case.